# intersection of one vector of set

Tags: c++, set, intersection

i have a vector of set and i want to do compare to get intersection of all these sets

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main() {

    
    vector<set<string>>data;


    string courses;
    int students = 0, numberOfCourses = 0;
    cin >> students;

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        cin >> numberOfCourses;
        set<string>st;
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfCourses; j++) {
            cin >> courses;
            st.insert(courses);
        }                                                       
        data.push_back(st);
    }



    
    


    
    

}
```

i searched but all answers about comparing two different vectors i want to compare same vector

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to know the courses that have all students enrolled in.

When you do `st.insert(courses);` you know that a specific student has a given course.

So, if you add `map<string, int> numberOfStudentsInCourse;` and

```
st.insert(courses);
numberOfStudentsInCourse[courses]++;
```

Then you just need to check, at the end, which `numberOfStudentsInCourse` have their `second` member equal to the number of students.

I'm not going to write the full code for you :-).

Comment: ok thank,  wanna know all the courses that have all students enrolled in to do intersection to make exam time table

Comment: pleasse can you explain more clearly